# Selecting geometric objects on a 2d view

Tags: algorithm, opengl, geometry, drawing, cad

I want to ask some faster way if possible to identify the closest object to my touch. I have thousands of lines, polygons, circles and rectangles. Bounding rectangle method is my current option.

Answer (score 1):

http://0fps.net/2015/01/18/collision-detection-part-2/

The papers linked there are very good. Especially these two.

http://pub.ist.ac.at/~edels/Papers/1983-J-04-RectangleIntersections:PartI.pdf
https://users.cs.duke.edu/~edels/Papers/1983-J-05-RectangleIntersections:PartII.pdf

Although they deal with rectangle intersections, but you probably can model your finger as a rectangle. Even if you don't, the data structures are useful.

If you want something a bit less optimal, you can do a line sweep type solution. Just sort the things on one axis. The papers basically do this, but on all axes.